# MongoDB Go Driver Not Auto-Populating Embedded Document

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm working on a educational Go application using the MongoDB Go driver and facing an issue with embedded documents. I have a `Blog` struct that embeds an `Author` struct, but the author information isn't being automatically populated when I decode the blog from the database.

```
type Blog struct {
    ID       primitive.ObjectID `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
    // ... other fields
    AuthorID primitive.ObjectID `bson:"author_id"`
    Author   Author             `bson:"-"`
}

type Author struct {
    ID   primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id"`
    Name string             `bson:"name"`
}
```

And i'm using a `cursor` to get the records from DB

```
var blogs []Blog
cursor, err := coll.Find(context.TODO(), bson.D{})
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    return []Blog{}
}

err = cursor.All(context.TODO(), &blogs)
```

However the author information always comes as this,

```
"Author": {
    "ID": "000000000000000000000000",
    "Name": ""
}
```

But the author id is populating correctly,

```
{
    "id": "659906e6f3a7ec5556b4fa41",
    "title": "Defense the travel.",
    "content_text": "...",
    "created_at": "2023-03-16T19:06:12.184269",
    "updated_at": "2023-03-16T19:06:12.184272",
    "AuthorID": "659906b7f3a7ec5556b4fa40",
    "Author": {
        "ID": "000000000000000000000000",
        "Name": ""
    }
}
```

1. Is this manual population of embedded documents expected behavior? Doesn't MongoDB Go driver handles that?
2. Are there any alternative approaches or techniques to handle embedded documents with the bson:"-" tag more efficiently?
3. Would removing the bson:"-" tag be advisable, or does it introduce potential issues?

Comment: I'm confused at what you're trying to do. It seems like a mix of relational database and document database techniques. Do you have (or want to have) a separate collection for Authors? If not, then eliminate the AuthorID, and modify the Author tag to `bson:"author"`. In this scenario, you query the book and get the author as an embedded document/field. The "-" is a flag to ignore this field, so no surprise you have no Author info populated in the DB.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still new to MongoDB. I tried your suggestion but still no luck. I get the same result as before. What I'm trying to achieve is to get all the blogs with their authors, like this ```{"id":"659906e6f3a7ec5556b4fa41","title":"Defense the travel.","Author":{"ID":"123123123123","Name":"Malinda Weerasinghe"}}```

Comment: Also i have a authors collection

Comment: MongoDB does not work the same as relational DBs in this way. The workflow is to make two transactions. 1. Create or update the Author, retrieving the ID. 2. Create the Blog, embedding the authorID in this document. The official docs here refer to this as a "manual reference". https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/database-references/#std-label-document-references

Comment: @BrianWagner Well, one ***could*** embed the Author in a blog post - and in some scenarios, this actually could make sense. However, you are of course right that it has to be populated manually.